# multiple step function for a single flow system

Tags: simulink

For Matlab simulink, how does one go about generating multiple step function at different conditions for a system

I am trying to simulate a simple flow through a tank and controlling the temperature within. At various interval say time at 10ses and 20secs i intend to draw out different flowrate/flow amount of water.

With the system designed, how do I show on a single scope how Flow in changes with  the different amount of flow out drawn.

Appreciate any kind advises

Comment: When you say "at different conditions" do you mean that the conditions are calculated as the model simulates, or do you know them in advance (i.e. you specify them before the simulation starts)?

Comment: Know them in advance

Comment: There are many different ways of doing this, for example defining the data in MATLAB and using a [From Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block or using multiple [Step](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/step.html) blocks summed together appropriately.  But to start I'd suggest you look at the [Signal Builder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/signalbuilder.html) block.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of doing this, for example defining the data in MATLAB and using a [From Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block or using multiple [Step](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/step.html) blocks summed together appropriately.  But to start I'd suggest you look at the [Signal Builder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/signalbuilder.html) block.

To view multiple signals at once in the same Scope, either set the scope up to have multiple inports, or [Mux](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/mux.html) the signals together and feed them in in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks Phil, managed to get the signal output generated. appreciate the help